# Find if a substring exists in file through regex in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have a build log file. I need to find if build failed or not .The log will have only "Build exited with errorcode 0" if it is passed. Now what I am looking for in the log file is regex similar to this  "Build exited with errorcode *", where * could be any return value except zero. If substring is found , the build has failed

For example:

1. If "Build exited with errorcode 0" is found then build passed.
2. If both "Build exited with errorcode 0", "Build exited with errorcode 1" , then build failed

It could be really done in python or other language but I am looking to do it terminal through regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if grep -Eq 'Build exited with errorcode ([^0]|[^[:space:]]{2,})' logfile; then
    echo build failed
else
    echo build passed
fi
```

This will print `build failed`, if the log file contains any instance of the above string, where the word after `errorcode` is anything other than a single zero. If you want `build failed` for anything other than one *or more* zeroes, you could instead use: `grep -q 'Build exited with errorcode [^[:space:]]*[^0][^[:space:]]*'`.

Note that in either case, even a period in the logfile (`Build exited with errorcode 0.`) would print 'failed'.

In other words, *all* instances of this string must be `Build exited with errorcode 0` for `passed` (or up to multiple zeroes for the second example, like `000` or `0`).

Comment: Log file does have some text after errorcode 0. For ex:  [buildfarm-ssh] [36m[39m NOTE: Build exited with errorcode 0[0m[0m      .

      
        So getting build failed on running your command

Comment: Removing these color codes from logs made it worked. Thanks

Comment: @NishantSharma : I don't know where your logfile comes from, but any professionally written application, should use colour information in its output only if it writes directly to a terminal with colour capabilities. If the terminal can't do colours, or if stdout is redirected to a file, it should by default omit colorization.

Comment: @user1934428 makes a relevant point. At the very least check if the program has a flag to turn color off. If not, I like the `ansi2txt` command from the `colorized-logs` package to remove colors. It can also be done with the right `sed` command.

Comment: @dan can you help with understanding what this regex do "[^[:space:]".

Comment: Sure. It means any _non_ whitespace character. `[abc]` is a character set, matching any of the characters inside the square brackets (eg `a` `b` or `c`). `[:space:]` is a [POSIX character class](https://github.com/micromatch/posix-character-classes) - a label for "any whitespace character". Inside square brackets, `^` is negation - it means NOT these characters. So together, `[^[:space:]]` is any non-whitespace character. Adding the kleene star (`*`), means zero or more non whitespace characters, adding the range (`{2,}`) means two or more.

Answer (score 0):

document content:

```
mm,bn,hello,ssdenl.
sdfsdf,dfdf,dfdfe,ggg.
sdfd,gfgf
dfdfgfgdfgsdfgsdfg
dfgfdg,sdfsdfdhello.sdfasdfas/
sdfsdfdfgdfgdsfhellosdfasdfasdf
sdfasdfdfgffghjdkfjglfdg
```

Look for the "hello" field

```
^(?!.*hello).*$
```

Comment: I am not trying to find regex for hello but hell* , so words could be helle , hella , etc except hello